# SQL SELECT: new column with values based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following SQL result from a SELECT:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
A    | 10   | 20
B    | 10   | 20
C    | 10   | 20
```

I want to have an additional column `col4` in the results which is filled based on the following conditions:

- if `col1` is `A`, then `col4` should be filled with the value from `col2`
- if `col1` is `B`, then `col4` should be filled with the value from `col3`
- if `col1` is `C`, then `col4` should be filled with the value `-`

The expected result therefore looks like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
A    | 10   | 20   | 10
B    | 10   | 20   | 20
C    | 10   | 20   | -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your columns are integers, then you shouldn't use an actual `-` as the result:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       CASE 
          WHEN col1 = 'A' THEN col2
          WHEN col1 = 'B' THEN col3
          WHEN col1 = 'C' THEN NULL
       END col4
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Now, if you do want a string as a result for `col4`, then you could use:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       CASE 
          WHEN col1 = 'A' THEN CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(10))
          WHEN col1 = 'B' THEN CAST(col3 AS VARCHAR(10))
          WHEN col1 = 'C' THEN '-'
       END col4
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```